export-to-csv return undefined rows
I have a funcion y typescript that download a csv file, but the rows in the files shows
as undefined and dont know why, I think that is a problem with async of the data that I bring but I dont know really,
I try to understand why I my data is showing undefined in the console.log and the csv
 const downloadCSV = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);


    try {
      const result = await getDataToExport();
      const CSVData = getCSVColumnsData(result);
      let headers = [
        "Vehículo",
        "Concesionario",
        "Conductor",
        "Fecha/Hora",
        "Dirección",
        "Evento",
        "Descripción",
        "Responsable de Revisión",
        "Acción",
        "Justificar",
        "Responsable de Acción",
      ];
      console.log(headers, "headers");

      console.log(CSVData, "data del csv");

      const options = {
        fieldSeparator: ';',
        quoteStrings: '"',
        decimalSeparator: '.',
        showLabels: true,
        showTitle: true,
        title: 'My Awesome CSV',
        useTextFile: false,
        useBom: true,
        useKeysAsHeaders: false,
        headers: headers
      };

      const csvExporter = new ExportToCsv(options);
      csvExporter.generateCsv(CSVData);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  };```


is  getDataToExport  function perfom api call?

yes,is a api call, another think that I realize that if I put   useKeysAsHeaders: true in options the csv works perfect but with my headers doesnt work

I believe you just missed the data property. When you retrieve data through an api call normally the response wrap with the data property, so changing your code like following should fix the issues:
 const result = await getDataToExport();
 const CSVData = getCSVColumnsData(result.data);


I tryed many ways but still give me the same result, i will  reinstall the library or search  a new one

update: I reinstall the library and the problem was in my npm version, I installed  a older version and worked perfeclly
